# Freeimage ANSI C Codeblock Windows - linking - newbie

Tags: c, windows, compilation, codeblocks

It's begining for me so please forgive me language and knoweledge.

I use ANSI C, CodeBlock and Windows.

I am following README.minGW but in the begining I encounter on problem with

```
gcc -oFreeImageTest.exe FreeImageTest.c -lFreeImage
```

What do I exactly here? I get error:

```
gcc: error: FreeImageTest.c: No such file or directory
```

I need make a program Which load pictures and showing position from exif gps.

I am loooing too for any examples in C using this library but I can't here.

Please, help me.

Comment: If you use Code::Blocks why are you building manually from the command line? Why don't you let Code::Blocks handle all that, and it will know the location of each source file used. And that's the problem you have, that you try to build in a location where the source file doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't understand how it works. Can you give me main topic whitch I must read to know what I must do? 

What must I do to use Code::Blocks for that?

Comment: If [the user manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/user-manual), or [the FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ), or [the wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Main_Page) or even [their forums](http://forums.codeblocks.org/) can't help you, then I don't know if anyone here can help you either.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in the folder where you installed free image, like this

[image]

Below is a codeblocks project file.
Copy and paste this into a file with the extension .cbp in the folder you created

Open the project file in codeblocks

Build

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
    <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
    <Project>
        <Option title="free_image_cb" />
        <Option pch_mode="2" />
        <Option compiler="gcc" />
        <Build>
            <Target title="Debug">
                <Option output="../bin/free_image_cb" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Debug/" />
                <Option type="1" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-g" />
                </Compiler>
            </Target>
            <Target title="Release">
                <Option output="../bin/free_image_cb" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Release/" />
                <Option type="1" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-O2" />
                </Compiler>
                <Linker>
                    <Add option="-s" />
                </Linker>
            </Target>
        </Build>
        <Compiler>
            <Add option="-Wall" />
            <Add option="-fexceptions" />
            <Add directory="../Dist/x32" />
        </Compiler>
        <Linker>
            <Add library="FreeImage" />
            <Add directory="../Dist/x32" />
        </Linker>
        <Unit filename="../Examples/Generic/BatchLoad.cpp" />
        <Extensions>
            <code_completion />
            <envvars />
            <debugger />
        </Extensions>
    </Project>
</CodeBlocks_project_file>
```